# understanding relevance of Lie vs topological groups

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, topological-groups

A silly easy to state question. When dealing with topological groups, I'm trying to understand more profoundly the advantages of having a Lie group structure against just a topological one. Can somebody please illustrate this more in depth?

I understand what it implies right away, say having topological against differentiable manifolds and so on, but I guess I could really use examples/good guidance in this specific case to grasp better the full implications of being a Lie group?

sorry if i'm being too vague here, any help is happily appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Naturally, Lie groups admit enough structure to support differential calculus and associated tools.

Conversely, being a topological group (rather than a Lie group) is not analogous to being a topological manifold (rather than a smooth manifold): "Most" topological groups aren't manifolds in any sense. For starters, think of the additive group of rationals or [$p$-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number), or the countable product of cyclic groups of order two with the product topology (whose total space is [homeomorphic to the Cantor ternary set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Topological_and_analytical_properties)), or an [irrational winding on a torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_winding_of_a_torus).

Comment: In fact if a topological group is a topological manifold, then it has a structure of a Lie group.

Answer (score 7):

One of the most important features of Lie groups is that they can be studied by means of their [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Relation_to_Lie_groups). Difficult questions about the global geometry of a Lie group sometime translate to simpler algebraic questions about its Lie algebra.

For example, compact connected Lie groups can be classified in terms of [Dynkin diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram), which is an algebraic object associated to the Lie algebra.

A topological group has a priori no Lie algebra.